# FB.getLoginStatus triggering browser pop blocker. How can I stop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im calling FB.getLoginStatus, of the Facebook JS SDK, from a button click event. My problem is that if the status parameter is set to true, then the browser pop-up blocker gets triggered, preventing the login dialogue to show. However, when I have the status as false, popup blocker doesn't get triggered. 
I need have the status as true as my site needs to know if the user is logged into Facebook without having to refresh the page.  The False parameter value means that FB just gets the cached login status, which can be wrong if the user logs out of Facebook while still on your site.

How can I get around this?

here is some code that illustrates the problem

```
 $('.my-button').click(function () {

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

                if (response.status != 'connected') {

                    FB.login(function (r) {
                        if (r.status == 'connected') {
                            alert('logged in');
                        }
                    });
                }

            }, true);

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because when you pass forceCheck to getLoginStatus, the callback is called asynchronously, which severs its connection with the "click" event. The browser or popup blocker fails to find a user-initiated click event on the call stack, so it blocks the popup. I am currently being bitten by the same problem.

Options:

1) Call FB.login directly.

Disadvantage: ugly popup flash even for logged-in users.

2) Upon detecting with getLoginStatus that the user is not logged in (or app isn't authorized), insert a separate login button somewhere near $('.my-button'), possibly with a message saying that the user must click the login button to connect with Facebook. In that second button's click handler call FB.login() directly.

Disadvantage: -50 to conversion rate

I will now try 2) and report results.

Comment: Probably you can call FB.getLoginStatus before the user clicks on the button (eg on page load), store the result in a variable, and be able to call directly FB.login in the click handler, based on the variable status, no?